# Sphinx autodoc integrate decorated properties

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, properties, decorator, python-sphinx

I started using Sphinx for documenting my sqlalchemy-driven app.

One of typical uses of SA in attribute manipulation is using `hybrid-property` decorator.

Now my problem is I get no doc entry for `name`:

```python
class User(GeneralTable):
    '''User'''
    ...
    @hybrid_property
    def name(self):
        '''
        User name

        :rtype: unicode
        '''
        if self._name is None:
            return 'anonymous'
        else:
            return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, name):
        '''
        :type name: unicode
        '''
        self._name = name
```

while changing `hybrid_property` to standard `property` I get it documented.

Is there a way to extend Sphinx to adopt with `hybrid_property` the same `property` behavior?

My current workaround is to put a name `.. attribute::` entry in `User` class doc.

Comment: @zzzeek: [Issue created](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/issue/748/sphinx-autodoc-does-not-integrate), let's see...

Comment: I have also encountered this bug. Using SqlAlchemy 1.0.11, changing `@hybrid_property` to `@property` removes warnings in regards to the `sqlalchemy.exc.UnboundExecutionError: Could not locate a bind configured on mapper Mapper|Table|table_name` Exception